# Nginx stream block with wildcard filtering of subdomains

Tags: nginx, transparent-proxy

I have set up an Nginx server as L4 Proxy(Forward Proxy With Stream Module), with the following configuration in the nginx.conf file;

```
stream {
resolver 8.8.8.8;
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_preread on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
    proxy_pass $ssl_preread_server_name:$server_port;
  } 
}
```

everything works fine, with the configuration above.
but let's say I want to limit the access of the URLs passing to my proxy server.Not by limiting the IP address but with URL names.

I did a research and setup the following configuration file and somehow I was able to control the URLs passing to my proxy.

But the issue starts from here. If a large website is called, since it has many links or subdomains loaded behind the scene, and knowing that I have limited the URLs allowed to pass, and wildcarding subdomains is not working in stream block, I am not able to load the requested website completely.

Is there a solution to have it used in stream block to support wildcard for subdomain of domain?
my new configuration is as below:

```
stream {


 map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
     ipchicken.com ipchicken.com;
     www.bbc.com www.bbc.com;
     www.bbc.co.uk www.bbc.co.uk;
     bbci.co.uk bbci.co.uk;
}


server {

    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    listen 443;
    ssl_preread on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
    proxy_pass $name:$server_port;
   }
 }

 events {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `hostnames` keyword. With this keyword you can use `*.example.com` as a wildcard entry for `example.com` domain. Similarly as for `server_name` directive you can use `.example.com` for both `example.com` and `*.example.com`:

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    hostnames;
    .ipchicken.com    $ssl_preread_server_name;
    .bbc.com          $ssl_preread_server_name;
    .bbc.co.uk        $ssl_preread_server_name;
    .bbci.co.uk       $ssl_preread_server_name;
}
```

As an alternative you can use any regex within the `map` block, i.e.

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    # covers 'bbc.com', 'www.bbc.com' and 'static.bbc.com':
    ~^(?:www\.|static\.)?bbc\.com$    $ssl_preread_server_name;
    ...
}
```